# Reasons of a Windows Automatic Repair

Tags: windows-10, repair

I've been thru a few automatic repairs with my different Windows computer, and it got me thinking:
**what triggers an automatic repair?**

I've looked with different key words on google, and all results directs me to guides to fix automatic repairs issues, but this is not what I'm looking for.

I'd like to know what Windows looks for at boot to determine if the disk needs reparation or not.